# I cannot evenly space buttons

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

I am using constraint layout in android studio, I want to evenly space buttons on main activity, it works fine on mobile view, but when I try to switch to tablet view it gets messed up, is there any way to evenly space buttons on both views?[here is the problem in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RowTv.png)

Comment: add your xml, it'll be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [_chains_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains) for ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want an example for how chainStyle may be used, you can [look at one](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/res/layout/inventory_item.xml) of our public samples. Or here is a paste from the link:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_std_half"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccentLighter"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_corner_radius"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/cardview_padding"
>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sku_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sku_price"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is a Title placeholder"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sku_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sku_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="$4.99"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/sku_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="126dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/sku_description"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sku_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_std_half"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_std_half"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sku_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
            tools:text="This is a description placeholder, telling users how cool this item is"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```